# ASP.NET MVC Form Submit with Link instead of Button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have a simple login form (or any form for that matter), and be able to post it, not with a button, but with a link.

So no `input`, but `a`.

I've seen plenty of solutions for this type of question, and I've tried lots of different options, and every single time, nothing happens.

I've stripped all the JQuery from what I have, so this is the "base" situation: what's missing to make it submit the form?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
  { %>
       <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)%><br/>
       <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)%><br/>
       <a href="#" id="submit-link" class="button">Log In</a>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only way to make this happen is using javascript:

```
<form id="fooForm" action="/foo" method="post">
    <a href="#" id="submit_link" class="button">Log In</a>
</form>
```

and in javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('a#submit_link').click(function() {
        $('form#fooForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Although I would suggest you using a submit button:

```
<button type="submit">
    <a href="#" id="submit_link" class="button">Log In</a>
</button>
```

And try to [style it](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html) to look as an anchor. My suggestion is to always use submit buttons to submit forms. This is more semantically correct, you will also find that things like pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while editing a text field will submit the form which is kind of native. So do what's semantically correct and do the styling in CSS.

Comment: Is the `<button type="submit">` cross-browser compatible? I found out that IE7/IE6 needs an `<input type="submit" />` it won't submit a form with a `<button>`.

Comment: "Although I would suggest you using a submit button [...] And try to style it to look as an anchor." That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

If the only reason that you want to use a link instead of a button is to make it look different (whilst retaining the same functionalty), why not just style the button to look like a link...

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit the form" class="fakeLink"/>

<style type="text/css">

.fakeLink{
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: blue;
    cursor: hand;
} 
.fakelink:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

</style>
```

Unfortunately, the 'hover' style doesn't work with IE, but does with Firefox.

I'm not completley convinced that making a submit button look like a link is a good idea, but I'm sure that I've seen it done before.

Comment: Not the real answer, but +1 for the button styling.

Comment: Trust me, this isn't a fake answer ;-). I'm still interested to know the reason for wanting to submit the form via a link, rather than a button.

Comment: Because HTML is provided to us, I didn't write it myself.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap you could add the class "btn btn-link" to your submit button to make it look like a regular link instead of writing custom CSS for it like was done above.

Comment: Actually it must be `cursor: pointer;` because "hand" is not defined by [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor) -- at least since CSS 2.1

Answer (score 7):

You can add a [`click` handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit-link").click(function() {
    $("#loginForm").submit();
  });
});
```

Or to make it more reusable, give the link a class instead, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="submit-link button">Log In</a>
```

Then reference it that way:

```
$(".submit-link").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

This makes any `<elem class="submit-link">` work to submit the `<form>` it's in.

Comment: I'm using a similar solution, but I had to add a call to preventDefault() after submit(). Otherwise it did not work.

Comment: Didn't know the '.closest' jQuery selector. Very clever. :)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I would change in your solution that I would add the onclick event to your link in order to submit the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
  { %>
       <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)%><br/>
       <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)%><br/>
       <a href="#" id="submit-link" class="button" onclick="loginForm.submit();">Log In</a>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inline JavaScript

```
   <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
      Submit
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just put a onclick event on it?

```
<a href="#" id="submit-link" class="button" onclick="submitForm()">Log In</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitForm()
       {
          document.forms.item(0).submit();
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In razor syntax and to add on Amer's suggestion; here's successful implementation I used:

Add the `id` of your form in the BeginForm method in the `htmlAttributes`.

Then use the inline JavaScript HREF to reference the form by it's id and submit it.

```
using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "LogOff", controllerName:"Account", routeValues: new { Area = "" },method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new {id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```