# Send id from View to controller but not show in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I want to send an id from a view to controller in asp.net mvc razor, but I don't want to show id in url.  How can I achieve this?  What should I do?  Is there a way to solve my problem?

here is my code:

```
 @Url.Action("myaction", "controller", new { id = 1 }),

~/Home/myaction/1
```

For example, you see my url has 1, but I want to show my url like this:

```
~/Home/myaction
```

I know I am sending a value, but I don't know how to send it without it showing up in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a post request instead of a get request, this will solve your problem.

You can call this post request by using ajax.

Comment: but problem is i am on list screen this work on grid edit button. how can i achieve this..?

Comment: what do you mean by list screen could you provide an example

Comment: which grid are you using

Comment: It should have an onclick event or some thing similar you can make the ajax call in this event in javascript

Comment: On what event do you want this call to be made, also can you post some more code so there is a better chance of undersanding whats goin on and a better chance to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that at the end of the day it's just HTTP. Your normal anchor tag would generate a GET request. GET requests cannot have a body so the only way to pass the id would be through a URL. Another option would be to intercept the click event and do a POST or PUT request. Then you can include the id in the body. Take a look at this post for some asp.net examples:

[ASP.NET MVC Form Submit with Link instead of Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265756/asp-net-mvc-form-submit-with-link-instead-of-button)